# Ubuntu 15.10 stuck at shut down

Tags: shutdown

I installed ubuntu 15.10 on my desktop running on core i7 4930k, nvidia 780ti, 16gb ram, 120gb ssd.

Every time I am trying to shut down, it gets stuck at this screen:

[image]

And it remains stuck there. Any suggestions?

PS: I am very new to ubuntu.

Comment: Try this command and see weather you can shutdown the computer `sudo shutdown -h now `

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your reply. I just tried it. It gets me the same issue.

Comment: Are you using wifi by chance???

Comment: Hi, the same for me! Try to shutdown my PC and then it gets freeze with complete black screen and monitor in power saving mode. If I try to switch to console, I can't, if I try to press any key, the HDD led gets lit but nothing happens. Have to reset the PC manually! My mother is Gigabyte GA-Z97-HD3